# my script only working from console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I put inside my html doc.

when I load the html page the script is not working,but when I put the script inside the console then the script is working an making the effect I want on the html doc.

here is the script,what i'm doing wrong?

```
var maxRows = 10;
$('.table').each(function() {
var cTable = $(this);
var cRows = cTable.find('tr:gt(0)');
var cRowCount = cRows.size();

if (cRowCount < maxRows) {
    return;
}

cRows.each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('td:first').text(function(j, val) {
       return (i + 1) + " - " + val;
    }); 
});

cRows.filter(':gt(' + (maxRows - 1) + ')').hide();


var cPrev = cTable.siblings('.prev');
var cNext = cTable.siblings('.next');

cPrev.addClass('disabled');

cPrev.click(function() {
    var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

    if (cPrev.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    cRows.hide();
    if (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1 > 0) {
        cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1) + ')').show();
    } else {
        cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + ')').show();
    }

    if (cFirstVisible - maxRows <= 0) {
        cPrev.addClass('disabled');
    }

    cNext.removeClass('disabled');

    return false;
});

cNext.click(function() {
    var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

    if (cNext.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    cRows.hide();
    cRows.filter(':lt(' + (cFirstVisible +2 * maxRows) + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible + maxRows - 1) + ')').show();

    if (cFirstVisible + 2 * maxRows >= cRows.size()) {
        cNext.addClass('disabled');
    }

    cPrev.removeClass('disabled');

    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely running that script before the elements that it references exist.

Make sure that the `<script>` tag comes later in the page than the element with the class `table` or wrap your entire script in:

```
$(function(){

 ... Your entire script

});
```

in order to ensure that it does not execute until the DOM is ready.

Comment: where do I put the function name in the example you showed me?

Comment: @LiranTadmor Nowhere, it's an anonymous function (functions in Javascript don't need names). So your script should start off with `<script> $(function(){` and then all the code that you had between your script tags, and then it should end with `}); </script>`

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the whole thing with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* existing code */ });
```

The browser may be executing your code before the page has loaded and therefore before the elements exist.

Comment: Hi I have added $(document).ready(function () but still it only works in console

Answer (score 0):

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Try wrapping your code in this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

[The Source](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)