# Script only working in the console even with document.ready

Tags: javascript, html, console, developer-tools, google-developer-tools

I have a script that runs on a page. It doesn't work, but when I type it into the console then run it it works perfectly.

This might sound like other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781758/my-script-only-working-from-console), but I already have `$(document).ready()`. All the variables already defined here have been defined earlier in the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        var post_html = posts_html[i];
        var link = posts[i];
        console.log(i);
        name = $(post_html)[5].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementsByClassName('posts')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('posts')[0].innerHTML + '<a href="' + link + '" class="sidebar_link sidebar_posts_link"><li>' + name + '</li></a>'
        console.log(name + ' - ' + posts + ' - ' + i + ' - ' + posts[i] + ' - ' + link);

    }
});
```

Comment: What is `posts`? Also, please add the `HTML` too.

Comment: make sure you have jQuery included, also check the console for any errors.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @Ionut I have a page which loads lots of different pages. here is the repository: https://github.com/Booligoosh/blog the js from my question is in end_script.js. The pages I'm running it on is posts/test2.html

Comment: @rick I have "Uncaught ReferenceError: posts is not defined(…)" but when I type posts into the console it shows me something. After that I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined(…)"

Comment: at the momemt of execution posts is not defined. At this point which is the order of your scripts import? can you post the html with a short import description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add setTime out function in your code.please try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  setTimeout(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var post_html = posts_html[i];
    var link = posts[i];
    console.log(i);
    name = $(post_html)[5].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('posts')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('posts')[0].innerHTML + '<a href="' + link + '" class="sidebar_link sidebar_posts_link"><li>' + name + '</li></a>'
    console.log(name + ' - ' + posts + ' - ' + i + ' - ' + posts[i] + ' - ' + link);

}
},5000);});
```

Comment: thanks, worked like magic (even if the loading time is slightly delayed). I'll try and see the minimum wait needed.

Comment: I discovered I can reduce the time delay down to 5ms